# Android Studio: Failed to initialize editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new with Android Studio technology. I've just launched a new empty project from scratch on Windows 10 machine. At first in my activity_main.xml file I could see an error "editor is unavaible until next gradle synch". After clicking on "Synch Project with Gradle Files" the error message turns into "Failed to initialize editor" as you can see on the pic below:

[image]

As you can see build console shows no errors. Also green arrow on the top bar is muted. How can I fix this issue?

Android Studio version: 4.02
JDK version: 1.8.0_261

**Note** I've got Avast Antivirus installed on my computer. I'm not sure if it changes anything but in few similar topics people repored this program as an issue interfering with Android Studio. However my avast quarantine remains empty.

**Update/Solution** In my case it turned out that downgrading my Android Studio from 4.0.2 to 3.5.3 version solved this problem. Now everything works fine.

Comment: make sure you have installed all required SDK components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know for sure what causes this error but you can solve it by first closing the project and deleting the project.xml file in the .idea\codeStyles\ directory of your project, as soon as you reopen your project you will get a popup prompting you to reconfigure this file, after that everything should be okay,

Answer (score 22):

I don't know why it happened, it happened for me on a project that was working earlier. Helped me File -> Invalidate Cashes / Restart in Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the incompatible AGP version.
AGP = Android Gradle Plugin

You can resolve it by two methods.

1> upgrading the agp of your project.

2> downgrading the android studio version.

You can find all the versions over here.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?authuser=1

Recommended:- upgrade the agp of your project.

Comment: For me, the solution was to upgrade gradle. Thank you

Comment: Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant, you can fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

This will Helps me all the time :

Open the project then

File > Invalidate Caches and Restart > Invalidate Restart
This step will fix your project.
[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVjAn.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vayug.png)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I simply had to exit Android Studio and relaunch it. :)

Comment: thank you for your response. Please take a look at my update/solution section where I updated a solution which worked for me well.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here worked for me. I tried invalidating caches, restarting AS, rebooting my PC, deleting .gradle .idea, build and app/build
The only way I was able to make it work as before was to roll back to a saved copy I (luckily) had (v3.6.3).
The problem happened immediately after I naively clicked on the offered updates (AS+gradle).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting the inspectionProfiles folder under the project's.idea folder and upgrading the gradle version.

Version: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I had to clean install android studio but it didn't fix it until I deleted this folder `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio*`.

This might be because of Toolbox since that's what I was using to update android studio when this happend.

Answer (score 0):

Update Gradle and plugins in project to latest, then invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

To Solve failed to initialize editor in android studio You need to update Android Gradle Plugin. First of all Open your File -> Project Structure ( Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S ) -> Project Then You need to update Android Gradle Plugin Version to 7.3.0 and Gradle Version to 7.4. And then You need to invalidate cache and restart your IDE will resolve your error.

reference: https://exerror.com/failed-to-initialize-editor-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Dolphin version today (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1). Now everything works.

Attention: After update you must invalidate your Android Studio Cache

Answer (score 0):

HI i update gradle plugin to 7.3.0 and wrapper to gradle-7.4-bin