# Failed to initialize editor error in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app which connects android wear to phone. To do this I first went to wear app section and then selected "Pair with empty phone app" but after I click finish it said that I need to sync gradle. After doing that it is showing me this error

I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750128/android-studio-failed-to-initialize-editor) and tried all 3 solutions but none of them work

[image: error]

Please help

Answer (score -1):

Try file->`Invalidate Caches / Restart` then click on `invalidate and restart`.
most of the times it works for built problems

OR try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73850730/18362930)

Comment: No it isn't working. I told in the question that I have tried all the solutions from the answer