# Android Studio Error : Failed to initialize editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**I got error "Design Editor is unavailable until next sync". Once i execute "Sync Project with gradle files" then error change to "Failed to initialize editor".**

Android Studio - Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1.

Platform - Zorin 16.2

Source - Snap store

AGP version - 8.0.1

Gradle Version - 8.0

Dependencies -

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

Java Version : openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18

I Tried

1.Revalidate cache

2.Downgrading AGP Version and gradle version

3.Restart

4.Tried all solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750128/android-studio-failed-to-initialize-editor)